# Perl: Empty/broken AoH

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

I have subroutine in my module which checks (regular) user password age using regex search on `shadow` file:

**Module.pm**

```
my $pwdsetts_dump = "tmp/shadow_dump.txt";
system("cat /etc/shadow > $pwdsetts_dump");
open (my $fh1, "<", $pwdsetts_dump) or die "Could not open file '$pwdsetts_dump': $!";

    sub CollectPWDSettings {
        my @pwdsettings;
        while (my $array = <$fh1>) {
            if ($array =~ /^(\S+)[:][$]\S+[:](1[0-9]{4})/) {
                my $pwdchange = "$2";
                if ("$2" eq "0") {
                    $pwdchange = "Next login";
                }
                my %hash = (
                    "Username"  =>  $1,
                    "Last change"   =>  $pwdchange
                );
                push (@pwdsettings, \%hash);
            }
        }
        my $current_date = int(time()/86400); # epoch 
        my $ndate = shift @_;                 # n-days
        my $search_date = int($current_date - $ndate);
        my @sorted = grep{$_->{'Last change'} > $search_date} @pwdsettings;

        return \@sorted;
    }
```

Script is divided in 2 steps: 
  1. load all password settings
  2. search for password which is older than n-days

In my main script I use following script:

```
my ($user_changed_pwd);
    if (grep{$_->{'Username'} eq $users_to_check} @{Module::CollectPWDSettings("100")}) {
        $user_changed_pwd = "no";
    }
    else {
        $user_changed_pwd = "yes";
    }
```

Problem occurs in first step, AoH never gets populated. I'm also pretty sure that this subroutine always worked for me and `strict` and `warnings` never complained about it, nut now, for some reason it refuses to work.

Comment: If you use `Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper \@pwdsettings;` just before your return, what do you get? My money would be on that `grep` filtering too much.

Comment: Dumper returns `$VAR1 = [];`, @pwdsettings is always empty.

Comment: OK. So that means upstream problem - is your `/etc/shadow` readable for the user running the script? (Why are you `cat`ing it, then opening hte tmp file anyway?)

Comment: Other possiblity is - regex doesn't match. Can you try printing `$array` and `%hash` (again, via `Dumper`).

Comment: Yes, script is running from sudo. I changed it just to see if module will create .txt file from shadow file, to see if it is problem with permissions.

Comment: You should be able to just read `shadow` directly.  But my `/etc/shadow` doesn't match that regex. (I'm probably not using the same password expiry mechanism though)

Comment: Actually, can I suggest instead just `split`ing the line from `/etc/shadow` on `:` and extracting field 1 and (3? I think?) that way?

Comment: `$array` is printable, and it returns content of `shadow_dump.txt`. `%hash` is not printable.

Comment: I didn't really understand that with `split`ing the line, but I know that regex is fully working, I test it on rubular with output from `shadow`.

Comment: Does `perl -ne 'print if m/^(\S+)[:][$]\S+[:](1[0-9]{4})/' /etc/shadow` give any output?

Comment: No, it's actually don't... But it works on Rubular and always worked before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87480/discussion-between-magomed-sega-ismailov-and-sobrique).

Comment: For some reason my grep function in my main script stopped to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just run your regex against my `/etc/shadow` and got no matches.  If I drop the leading `1` I get a few hits.

E.g.:

```
$array =~ /^(\S+)[:][$]\S+[:]([0-9]{4})/
```

But personally - I would suggest not trying to regex, and instead rely on the fact that [`/etc/shadow`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) is defined as delimited by `:`.

```
my @fields = split ( /:/, $array );
```

$1 contains a bunch of stuff, and I suspect what you *actually* want is the username - but because `\S+` is greedy, you might be accidentally ending up with encrypted passwords.

Which will be `$fields[0]`.

And then the 'last change' field - from [`man shadow`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) is `$fields[2]`.

Comment: That was a beautiful and elegant solution, thank you, problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex pattern is the main problem. Don't forget that `\S` matches any non-space character including colons `:`, and `\S+` will try to match as much as possible so it will happily skip over multiple fields of the file

I think using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to separate each record into colon-delimited fields is a better approach. I also think that, instead of the array of two-element hashes `@pwdsettings` it would be better to store the data as a hash relating usernames to their password history

Here's how I would write this. It prints a list of all usernames whose password history is greater than 90 days

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my @shadow = do {
    open my $fh, '<', '/etc/shadow' or die qq{Unable to open "/etc/shadow" for input: $!};
    <$fh>;
};

print "$_\n" for @{ collect_pwd_settings(90) };

sub collect_pwd_settings {

    my ($ndate) = @_;

    my %pwdsettings;

    for ( @shadow ) {
        my ($user, $pwdchange) = (split /:/)[0,2];
        $pwdsettings{$user} = $pwdchange;
    }

    my $current_date = time / ONE_DAY;

    my @filtered = grep { $current_date - $pwdsettings{$_} > $ndate } keys %pwdsettings;

    return \@filtered;
}
```